# Configure Citrix Xen App servers to use client-to-server redirection within Xen app sessions?

Tags: windows-server-2003, citrix

My Goal is to make client-to-server redirection work in citrix XenApp sessions.  I believe my problem is caused by the default behavior of client drive mapping, but I could be wrong.

Currently, I have ServerA with IE, and ServerB with Microsoft Word.  From my desktop, if I open a word document, ServerB launches Microsoft Word, and *opens the document*.  If I launch an IE session using XenApp on ServerA, and click on a word document, ServerB launches Word, but *the document does not open*.  If I connect to ServerA through RDP, and click on the same word document, ServerB launches Word, and the *document opens*.

I believe the problem is caused by the client drive mapping behavior, but I cannot find any way to change how it behaves.  When I open a word document and it works, ServerB has a drive mapped to the machine I am using.  So if I try to open it from my computer, it has a drive mapped to my computer, if I use ServerA through RDP it has a drive mapped to ServerA.  When I use a Citrix session on ServerA to open a word document, it has a drive mapped to my computer, not to ServerA.  I think that I need a drive mapped to ServerA.

I have followed the steps listed in this CTX article:

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX101808

I have also checked the documentation in the Citrix Administrators guide for our Client, and for our Version of XenApp. The application looks to be configured properly with the "%*" wildcard configured to receive the information from the client.  Client drive mappings are also enabled.

I cannot find any information on how to change the behavior of client drive mapping.

Environment:
Windows XP sp3 client
2003 sp2  Server 
Internet Explorer 7
Citrix XenApp 4.5 
Microsoft Word 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue, turns out I had not been searching for the correct magic phrase.  What I was looking for is under the pass-through client.

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX238200

Client drive mapping on the pass-through client was restricted to the drives on the client device. The client could not map local or network drives configured on the MetaFrame server in a pass-through session.
Local or network drives configured on the MetaFrame server can now be mapped by the pass-through client.

For version 10.xx

1. Run Regedit.
2. Navigate to: 
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Citrix\ICA Client\Engine\Configuration\Advanced\Modules\ClientDrive

Create the Reg Value: NativeDriveMapping

Reg Type: REG_SZ

Add the Value: True

When this flag is set, the client drives on the client device are not mapped and are not available. The drives configured on the MetaFrame server are mapped and are available to the pass-through client.